# Get header of CSV file in Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-file-upload

I'm building a django app that will let people upload CSVs that will be stored in S3 (based on `django-storages`) then processed by celery tasks which will then ingest them into the database.

These CSVs can be any size, from a few rows (where Django would store it as a `InMemoryUploadedFile`) to hundreds of megabytes (where django would use a`TemporaryUploadedFile`.)

I'm using a simple `ModelForm` on a generic `CreateView`, but I want to add a way to check the first row in the file (the header) to validate that the CSV has all the columns I need.

This would be pretty simple if I knew the path of the file. I'd just use python's standard file and csv handling functionality to read the first line into the `csv` module and check the fields. But how do I do that using an uploaded file where it may be in memory or it may be a temporary file, inside the modelform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will not spell it out for you, but it should be enough to unblock you.

From the looks of the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.TemporaryUploadedFile), you can use a built in method to get the temporary file path of a "TemporaryUploadedFile":

```
TemporaryUploadedFile.temporary_file_path()
```

To wrap this all up, you'll have to have some logic in your code to identify if it is an "InMemoryUploadedFile" or a "TemporaryUploadedFile". From there, you can look at each object differently to assess the columns.

Comment: Ahh, so if I use that and use exclusively TemporaryUploadedFiles I'll at least get it working. Thanks! That at least gets it working. Would be nice to have a way to do it with both InMemoryUploadedFiles and local files.

Comment: There is a way, youll just have to use conditional statements to decide which code to use. By the way, could you mark this answer as correct?